# CORS Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am totally new to Node.js and am just trying to get some example code running however I keep running into issues with CORS.

Server.js

```
    var http = require('http');
    var io = require('socket.io');

 server = http.createServer(function(req, res){    
 });
server.listen(8080);
// socket.io
var socket = io.listen(server,  { origins: '*:*' });

// Enables CORS
var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-   Length, X-Requested-With');

// intercept OPTIONS method
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
  res.send(200);
}
else {
  next();
}
};


// enable CORS!
socket.use(enableCORS);
//--------------
socket.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('message', function(msg){
  socket.broadcast(msg);
  })
});
```

client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.7:8080');
socket.on('message', function(msg){
alert(msg);
console.log(msg);
});
```

I tried installing the CORS module for node.js but I keep getting messages in firefox debugger, but I still keep getting this:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://8080/socket.io/1/?t=1400151675528. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
ReferenceError: socket is not defined client2.html:8
ReferenceError: socket is not defined
```

Comment: Is your client code being served on the same host AND port as your node server? If not, try to serve your client code using the Node server so it uses the same host and port. Then you shouldn't have this issue as CORS will not apply. Also, It seems like you're using raw Node without a framework. Using something like Express.js (a very light framework) would make serving static files easy (as well as several other essential things). Sorry if I'm not directly answering your question. I'm not a CORS expert. But I do love Node and want to give you some good starter advice. Good luck.

Comment: The server is listening to 8080, and the client code is listening to 127.0.0.7:8080

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8080 =/= 127.0.0.7:8080 ... Hence the issue. My advice is to spend half an hour learning Express and using the one server. Otherwise learn about the HTTP headers to disable CORS and set them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to set CORS headers on the target server only. You also need to set the appropriate headers for the web server that serves your **client-side HTML file**.

Since you did not mention how you serve your client-side files, I can not post the right solution for you. But if you are using Apache httpd, you could put the following in the configuration or `.htaccess`:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, x-http-method-override, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```